I am still new to LWC. I am trying to change the bg through the button click. What am I doing wrong?
<template>
<lightning-card title="Test id" class="bt" icon-name="utility:hierarchy">
    <div id="eyed">
    <p id="para">
        <span class="containt">
        Hey This is me testing<br> 
        how LWC works compared to HTML<br>
        </span>
        <span class="containbt">
        <input type="button" value="color yay" id="baton" onclick={handleClick}/>
        </span>
    </p>
    </div>
</lightning-card>

    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class Testinglwc extends LightningElement {
    handleClick(){
        bodi = this.template.querySelector('#eyed');
        bodi.classList.toggle('bg-col');
    }
}


Could you provide your CSS file's content as well please? Just [edit] to add it.

Documentation states (emphasis mine)

Don’t use ID selectors with querySelector. The IDs that you define in HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it won’t match the transformed ID.

That's the issue, this line bodi = this.template.querySelector('#eyed'); it returns null since once the LWC renders, the ID in HTML is changed by the framework.
In this case you could use the lwc:ref directive instead of the id attribute:
HTML
<lightning-card title="Test id" class="bt" icon-name="utility:hierarchy">
    <div lwc:ref="eyed">
    <p id="para">
        <span class="containt">
        Hey This is me testing<br> 
        how LWC works compared to HTML<br>
        </span>
        <span class="containbt">
        <input type="button" value="color yay" id="baton" onclick={handleClick}/>
        </span>
    </p>
    </div>
</lightning-card>

Then in JS you can access to that element via this.refs.yourId.
JS
handleClick() {
    const bodi = this.refs.eyed;
    bodi.classList.toggle('bg-col');
}

